# Query selects all columns even though only one column is selected

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, ef-core-7.0

I have encountered an issue while working with Entity Framework Core 7 where the generated SQL query appears to select all columns from the table, even though I am selecting only one column in my LINQ query.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
var data = dbContext.CandidateData
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .Where(x => x.CollegeCode == collegeCode
                                && x.Status == CandidateStatus.Active 
                                && ((x.Year == startYear && 
                                     (x.Month >= startMonth && x.Month <= endMonth)) 
                                    || (isDifferentYear ? (x.Year == endYear && x.Month <= endMonth) : false)));

if (someCondition)
{
    beginningScore = await data
                             .Where(x => x.Year == fromDate.Year 
                                         && x.Month == fromDate.Month)
                             .Select(x => x.BeginningScore)
                             .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

CandidateData class :

```
public class CandidateData
{
public int CandidateId {get;set;}
public CollegeCode CollegeCode {get;set;} // this is enum value
public int Year { get; set; }
public int Month { get; set; }
public decimal BeginningScore { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent Configuration :

```
public class CandidateDataConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<CandidateData>
  {
      public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CandidateData> builder)
      {
          builder.HasKey(e => e.CandidateId);
          builder.Property(e => e.CandidateId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
          builder.HasIndex(e => new { e.CollegeCode,e.Year, e.Month }).IsUnique().HasDatabaseName("CandidateDataIndex");
      }
  }
```

In this code, I'm querying the database to fetch data based on certain conditions. However, even though I'm selecting only the `BeginningScore` column, the generated SQL query seems to select all columns from the table.

I have verified that my LINQ query explicitly selects only the `BeginningScore` column, and there are no navigation properties involved. Despite this, the SQL generated by EF Core pulls all columns from the table.

Can someone help me understand why EF Core 7 might be behaving this way and how I can optimize my query to only select the specified column?

I've tried using `SingleOrDefaultAsync()`, using anonymous object projection, but nothing worked as of now, it always pulls all the columns in final generated SQL and also to note specifically here `CandidateData` table doesn't have single navigational property & data is `IQueryable` type.

Comment: Do you have unmapped class properties used in the query? Can we see the class and relevant fluent configuration if any?

Comment: @IvanStoev ive updated the description &  added the Simplified version of CandidateData class and its fluent configuration

Comment: `BeginningScore` mapped to database?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv yes its mapped to database

Comment: Please share the full generated SQL statement. Please also show the real code since your model doesn't have a `beginningScore` property as shown in `.Select(x => x.beginningScore)`; C# is case sensitive, the property is `BeginningScore`.

Comment: @PriceOne Ok, but still some enum and property are missing. In general what we asked for is the minimal code we could copy/paste into a clean project and reproduce the query. Make sure you can reproduce it in a clean project as well with the posted code. Otherwise there is nothing we can do. For instance, after making the sample code compilable, the generated SQL query always starts with `SELECT TOP(1) [c].[BeginningScore] FROM [CandidateData] AS [c]`, i.e. does not reproduce the behavior in question.